# How to find Multiple div reach top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a survey page divided into sections. As the user scrolls, each section's header sticks to the top of the screen until the next section is reached. I was able to do it for the first and second section but I am not sure how to do it for the third one. There must be a better way to do this.

**Here is my code and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/azr7dwuu/)**

Thank you

```
var s = $("#block2 .question-title-block");
    var pos = s.position();          
        $(window).scroll(function() {           
             var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();     
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 404) {          
            $('#block1 .question-title-block').addClass("sticky");                                   
                           if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
                         $('#block2 .question-title-block').addClass("sticky");
                         $('#block1 .question-title-block').removeClass("sticky");
        }  
        else{           
             $('#block2 .question-title-block').removeClass("sticky");          
        }
    } 
    else{
      $('#block1 .question-title-block').removeClass("sticky");
      $('#block2 .question-title-block').removeClass("sticky");    
    }   
 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be applied to as many elements as you want, don't use them individually, use their class. Here is what you can do:

```
var titleBlocks = $(".question-title-block");

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

    titleBlocks.each(function(){

        $(this).toggleClass('sticky', $(this).parent().offset().top <= windowpos);

    });

});
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Nice use of `toggleClass`.  I posted while your answer was hidden, but I like yours more than mine so I deleted it.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Haha thanks. Yes, I hid it because I needed to fix a glitch, and then I saw yours, which was similar except for the toggle.

Answer (score 1):

try this (allows for any number of question blocks):

```
var containers = $('.question-block-container');
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    containers.each(function () {
        var container = $(this),
            title = container.find('.question-title'),
            contOffsetTop = container.offset().top,
            conOffsetBottom = contOffsetTop + container.outerHeight() + 60; // 60 is margin bottom

        if (windowpos >= contOffsetTop && windowpos <= conOffsetBottom) {
            if (!title.hasClass("sticky")) {
                title.addClass("sticky");
            }
        } else if (title.hasClass("sticky")) {
            title.removeClass("sticky");
        }
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/azr7dwuu/6/)

Comment: Tip for the OP, if you want to stop the stick div from jumping when you get to the second scroll point, change the CSS for `.question-block-container` swap `margin-bottom:60px;` with `padding-bottom:60px;`